# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. What goes on when the Hessian at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm doing undergraduate research on navigation functions which are simply cost functions. There is a lot of importance when the Hessian of the critical points of cost function is full rank. I was hoping someone could explain what goes on when this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, if the Jacobian has full rank~$1$ then the level set of $f$ at a point $p \in \mathbb R^n$ can be linearly approximated by the tangent plane, which is a level set of a linear function $L(x) = ax_1 + ... + a x_n + b)$.

Similarly, if the Jacobian and the Hessian have full rank, then the level set of $f$ at $p$ can be quadratically approximated by a "conic", which is a level set of a quadratic function. The geometry of this conic depends on the index of the Hessian, i.e. the number of negative eigenvalues. For instance, if $n=3$ then the best approximating conic is a sphere if the index is $0$ or $3$, and is a hyperboloid if the index is $1$ or $2$.

Comment: That's interesting. What field of math deals with this type of stuff?

Comment: It's called "Morse Theory", for example there is a graduate level math book with that title by Milnor.